# Terraform, providers miss inherits on module

Tags: module, terraform, provider

*Terraform v0.14.8*

Got this probleme when I try to launch terraform init, the provider *registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aci* is not found

I want to use my provider : registry.terraform.io/ciscodevnet/aci

$ terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:

```
.  
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/ciscodevnet/aci] 0.5.4  
└── module.bride_domain_2001  
        └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aci]
```

My question : How to force registry.terraform.io/**ciscodevnet**/aci on module ?

How i call my module :

```
    module "bride_domain_2001" {
      source = "./modules/bride_domain_2001"

      aci_vrf_vrf_training_id= aci_vrf.vrf_training.id
      aci_tenant_tenant_training_id= aci_tenant.tenant_training.id
    }
```

Expected Behavior
The in-house provider should be inherited from the parent and used

Actual Behavior
Terraform doesn't use inheritance from parent module

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your child module `bride_domain_2001` is missing a `required_providers` entry to specify that it depends on `ciscodevnet/aci`, which is causing Terraform's backward compatibility behavior to assume you meant `hashicorp/aci`.

To fix it, add a `required_providers` entry to your child module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aci = {
      source = "ciscodevnet/aci"
      # (possibly also a >= version constraint)
    }
  }
}
```

Once you add this, Terraform will see that the root module and the child module both depend on this same provider `ciscodevnet/aci`, and so your [configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html) for the provider should then be inherited by resources belonging to that provider in the child module.