# Terraform child module does not inherit provider from root module

Tags: terraform

### My problem

I am having trouble defining the provider for my module.
Terraform fails to find the provider's plugin when I run `terraform init` and it shows the wrong provider for my module when I run `terraform providers`.

### Setup

I am using Terraform **version 1.3.7** on Debian 11.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

I have a main.tf where is my main configuration and modules. In this example I use a single module for creating a docker container.

```
.
├── main.tf
└── modules/
    └── container_module/
        └── main.tf
```

In the root module `project/main.tf` file, I define the provider and call the module:

```
terraform {                                                                     
  required_providers {                                                          
    docker = {                                                                  
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"                                            
      version = "3.0.1"                                                         
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
}                                                                               
                                                                                 
provider "docker" {                                                             
  host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"                                          
}                                                                               
                                                                                
module "container" {                                                            
  source = "./modules/container_module"                                         
}
```

In the `modules/container_module/main.tf`, I create the docker container resource:

```
resource "docker_image" "debian" {
  name = "debian:latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "foo" {
  image = docker_image.debian.image_id
  name  = "foo"
}
```

### What I expect to happen

When I run `terraform init`, it should download the provider's plugin from `kreuzwerker/docker`.

### What actually happens

Instead, terraform downloads the plugin from `kreuzwerker/docker` once, then attempt to download it again from `hashicorp/docker`.

Here's the command's output:

```bash
terraform init
Initializing modules...
- container in modules/container_module

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/docker...
- Finding kreuzwerker/docker versions matching "3.0.1"...
- Installing kreuzwerker/docker v3.0.1...
- Installed kreuzwerker/docker v3.0.1 (self-signed, key ID BD080C4571C6104C)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/docker: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/docker
│ 
│ Did you intend to use kreuzwerker/docker? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on
│ hashicorp/docker, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵
```

When I run `terraform providers` I get two different sources depending on the file:

```bash
terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker] 3.0.1
└── module.container
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/docker]
```

According to the documentation, the child modules should inherit the provider from their parent:
[Default Behavior: Inherit Default Providers](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/module-providers#default-behavior-inherit-default-providers):

> If the child module does not declare any configuration aliases, the providers argument is optional. If you omit it, a child module inherits all of the default provider configurations from its parent module. (Default provider configurations are ones that don't use the alias argument.)

### I have already checked this

- [Do terraform modules need required_providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68218458/4510359)

  - This answer confirms the provider inheritence.
- [Terraform provider's resources not available in other tf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040039/terraform-providers-resources-not-available-in-other-tf-files/75054188#75054188):

  - This question didn't help.
- [Terraform, providers miss inherits on module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66658707/terraform-providers-miss-inherits-on-module)

  - This answer to this similar question says that I should add `required_providers` in the child module, but it is for an older version and it contradicts what I saw elsewhere.
- I have the same issue when I create a `providers.tf` file in the root directory.

### My question

How should I declare my provider so that the child module can inherit the provider from the root module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kreuzwerker/docker` is **not a hashicorp provider**. Thus as explained [here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/using-a-non-hashicorp-provider-in-a-module/21841), you have to explicitly define `required_providers` in each module, as such providers are not inherited.

Comment: I didn't get that point. It works now. Thank you Marcin!

Comment: The important sublety here is that the child module inherits the provider _configuration_ -- that is, the `provider "docker"` block -- but it doesn't inherit the provider _dependency_, which you declare in the `required_providers` block. You need to specify the dependency in all modules because otherwise Terraform doesn't know that "docker" in the child module refers to the same provider as "docker" in the parent module -- the child module could've been intending a provider named "docker" published under a different organization, for example.

Comment: Once Terraform can see that both modules are intending to use `kreuzwerker/docker`, it can see that the configuration should be inherited automatically.

Comment: This isn't needed for providers in the `hashicorp` namespace only because in that case when Terraform's backward-compatibility behavior guesses that a provider is in the `hashicorp` namespace the two modules end up guessing the same address and so it "just works". But that's really just a consequence of how the backward-compatibility logic works, not something you should rely on. Better to always declare all of your provider dependencies, even if they are in the "hashicorp" namespace.